# Clear inline-blocks without using an empty div.clear between them?

Tags: css, css-float

I understand that the older technique for a situation like this would be to just put a blank  in between the two elements that I want to separate, but how would I do this in a more elegant and semantic way?

https://codepen.io/sharpdesigner/pen/oywgeo

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: center;
}
.block-container {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
.block-1 {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.block-2 {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h3>How do you get these two blocks to display stacked vertically instead of on the same line, without using a div.clear?</h3>

<div class="block-container">
  <a class="block-1" href="" title=""><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" /></a>
  <a class="block-2" href="" title="">a.block-2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: If you don’t want them inline, don’t tell them to be inline? Or what am I missing? Stacked as in one on top of another?

Comment: What if the first is a link and making it inline would make the link 100% of the page width? I will update the codepen to show this. Check it now, and try changing the first one to display: block. See how the link is the full width of the page instead of just where the image is? And yes, stacked on top of one another instead of inline.

Comment: You can set display:block; and set a max-width to the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using flex

```
.block-container {
  max-width: 1250px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```css
 
body {
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: center;
}
.block-container {
  max-width: 1250px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.block-1 {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.block-2 {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h3>How do you get these two blocks to display stacked instead of on the same line, without using a div.clear?</h3>

<div class="block-container">
  <a class="block-1" href="" title="">a.block-1</a>
  <a class="block-2" href="" title="">a.block-2</a>
</div>
```

**2nd Answer**
Make the block2 element `display: block`

```css
 
body {
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: center;
}
.block-container {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
.block-1 {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.block-2 {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto 30px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h3>How do you get these two blocks to display stacked instead of on the same line, without using a div.clear?</h3>

<div class="block-container">
  <a class="block-1" href="" title=""><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" /></a>
  <a class="block-2" href="" title="">a.block-2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What if i'm not using flex?

Comment: See the second snippet please

Comment: The issue is that they both need to be inline-block because neither have a set width. They scale with the size of the image in the first block and the size of the text in the second. I understand that changing one to a block will solve this, but I just didn't know if there was a standard way to clear lines when they were both inline-block.

Comment: You can add ad  br  tag between the two anchors to make them come in 2 line also . But i am not sure if you want to do that

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the issue correctly, Just try to put this CSS declaration on the parent container:

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

With this approach you avoid to transform the inline-block elements to a block elements.

---

> **pre-line** - This value will cause sequences of whitespace to collapse into a single space character. Line breaks will occur wherever necessary to fill line boxes, and at new lines in the markup (or at occurrences of "\a" in generated content). In other words, it’s like normal except that it’ll honor explicit line breaks.

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: center;
}
.block-container {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 30px auto;
  white-space: pre-line;

}
.block-1 {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.block-2 {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto 30px;
  display: inline-block;

}
```

```html
<h3>How do you get these two blocks to display stacked vertically instead of on the same line, without using a div.clear?</h3>

<div class="block-container">
  <a class="block-1" href="" title=""><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" /></a>
  <a class="block-2" href="" title="">a.block-2</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understood the questions correctly, but I suggest looking into CSS grid if it's applicable. I've altered your code pen just slightly to show what this would look like. You can display the elements vertically after specifying that you'd only like one column, in my example I've set the width of the column to `auto` using the `grid-template-column` attribute.

```
.block-container {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 30px auto;
    display:grid;

    /*by specifying that there is only one column, this should create vertical alignment.*/ 
    grid-template-column: auto;
 }

.block-1 {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto 30px;
    display: inline-block;
 }

.block-2 {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto 30px;
    display: inline-block;
 }
```